# Create table with Global secondary index using DynamoMapper and class Annotation

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am currently using Java dynamoMapper to create and query the table. When trying to create a table with a global secondary index, I get the following error

```
No provisioned throughput specified for the global secondary index
```

My java class representing the table has this attribute for the global secondary index.

```
@DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName="sender")
    public String getSender() {
    return sender;
}
```

Class to create table looks like this

```
public boolean createTable() {
try {
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
CreateTableRequest tableRequest =     mapper.generateCreateTableRequest(entityClass); // 1
tableRequest.setProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(1000L, 1500L)); // 2
client.createTable(tableRequest); // 3

    } catch (Error e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have searched the Amazon site for additional annotations and configuration but nothing came up for DynamoMapper. Is there anyway to do this using ORM or will i have to manually create by using a lower level API?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to set the provisioned throughput on each secondary index table that will be generated as well.

```
tableRequest.getGlobalSecondaryIndexes().get(0).setProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(10l, 10l));
```

Answer (score 4):

Extension to @Jeremy's answer.

If you have more than one GSI, then you may do it like below. Also you don't need to create ProvisionedThroughput object all the time if they are of same values.

```
 final ProvisionedThroughput provisionedThroughput = new ProvisionedThroughput(5L, 5L);
 createRequest.setProvisionedThroughput(provisionedThroughput);
 createRequest.getGlobalSecondaryIndexes().forEach(v -> v.setProvisionedThroughput(provisionedThroughput));
```